# Parsing WSDL: xx already defined

Tags: php, soap-client, xtrf

When I try to execute following PHP code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://.../translationManagementService/XTRFService?wsdl");
```

I get:

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:  'createCustomer' already defined in /data/r/e/reachlocalization.com/web/createuser.php:31 Stack trace: #0 /data/r/e/reachlocalization.com/web/createuser.php(31): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://.......') #1 {main} thrown in /data/r/e/reachlocalization.com/web/createuser.php on line 31

Am I doing something wrong or is this server related?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [PHP bug #45282](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45282).

You can try [Pear SOAP](http://pear.php.net/package/SOAP) implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Try to connect to `?singleWsdl` instead of `?wsdl`